# My Meyer lemon tree had so many diseases

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-care, diseases

So everything I read was to take curling or diseased leaves and branches off. I sprayed with neem oil and copper fungicide biweekly I live in zone 9 and the tree is in the ground with soil and compost and mulch on top. I got a little out of hand and now it has no leaves bc it was all diseased but it had so many baby lemons growing I was worried it would suck my tree dry so I took all the baby lemons off. Will my tree come back?! I’m still spraying with neem oil monthly and saw a new flower start to grow but no leaves.

Comment: Welcome! Doesn’t sound good - could we get a photo or two?

Comment: How do I put up a photo?

Comment: It says my pic is too big for some reason it still has green branches shooting out that had the lemons growing and the thorns.

Comment: You can [edit] your post any time. There’s a little picture icon, when you click it, the pop-up menu should guide you through the steps. Note that there’s a size limit for photos.